# wordpress plugin shown in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

hello i want to develop a wordpress plugin having same behaviour of post. But i want that my plugin is shown in admin panel under settings bar of wordpress admin panel. how can i Do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Settings: add_submenu_page('options-general.php',...)
[wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add new tab in settings menu than you can use "add_options_page"..

see here: [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page)